# How get User to email?

Tags: spring, jpa

I need get user to email with jpa

i have this code:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
    User findById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

When i tried this :

```
 User owner = userRepository.findById(user.getId()); //yes
    User user=userRepository.findByEmail(email);//no
```

My class User is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public User() {
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

I want to obtain a user through the user's email, if I can obtain it through his id but I also need to obtain it through email

Comment: can  you share your Model class

Comment: email is an unique column ? if not add this `@Column(unique=true)`

Comment: did you try List<User> findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);

Comment: @HienNguyen i get this []

Comment: @yaha try like this @Query("SELECT u FROM User u where u.email= :email")
userRepository.findByEmail(@Param("email")String email)

Comment: @Kalaiselvan good answer!!!

Comment: @Kalaiselvan 
I try it again with @Column(unique=true), and it works, I'm wrong to try with "email" and without quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you Model class "email" is not an unique so that it will return multiple rows to avoid that  add

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "User")
 public class User implements Serializable {
    .....
     @Column(unique=true,...)// .. add your extra
     private String email;
    .....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want top 1 result to be returned you could change the method

```
User findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
```

with

```
User findOneByEmail(String email);
```